# Consolidating Code into a Base Class when the properties are different object types

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have several classes that all have extremely similar code and I am wondering if it would make sense to combine the generic code, and how to go about it. Each class has a specific Model property and a specific Service property, but other than that they are pretty much the same.

Here is an example of the code I am working with:

```
public class Example1 {
    public Object1 Model { get; set; }  
    private Service1 Service {get;set;}

    protected bool Create()
    {
        try
        {
            Model = Service.Create(Model);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

So say I have 4 classes that all have the same `Create()` method syntax, but the property object types all differ. Is there a way I can transform that into 4 classes that each have their properties defined and then have the `Create()` method in one base class?

I would expect it to look something like below:

```
public class Example1 : Base {
    public Object1 Model { get; set; }
    private Service1 Service { get; set; }
}

public class Example2 : Base {
    public Object2 Model { get; set; }
    private Service2 Service { get; set; }
}

public class Example3 : Base {
    public Object3 Model { get; set; }
    private Service3 Service { get; set; }
}

public class Example4 : Base {
    public Object4 Model { get; set; }
    private Service4 Service { get; set; }
}

public class Base {

    // Wondering if this would do the trick; could be confusing though
    // public object Model { get; set; }
    // private object Service { get; set; }
    //

    protected bool Create()
    {
        try
        {
            Model = Service.Create(Model);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting stuck on how I should be providing the properties in the base class.

Thanks for any help. If this is not possible that is fine, I just wanted to make my code base a little less bloated.

EDIT:

One thing I thought may work is having the Model and Service defined in the Base class as Object, but then I was worried there would be confusion depending on where the property was being called from.

Comment: I'd recommend making your Base-Class abstract and make your models and services implement an Interface sharing the functions they have in common. Than use that interface in your Base-class for `Model` and `Service`. You might need to make your Service-Interface and Base-Class generic for passing the correct model type into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use generics with an abstract base class to get where you need to be:

```
public abstract class Base<TModel, TService> where TService: IService
{
    public TModel Model { get; set; }
    private TService Service { get; set; }

    protected bool Create()
    {
        try
        {
            Model = Service.Create(Model);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing you would have to change here is add a backing abstraction to your "service" type that has the reference to `Create()`.  Then you would have to restrict your generic to that abstraction (in my example above the abstraction is `IService`).  Your abstraction would look something like this:

```
public interface IService
{
    T Create(T input);
}
```

After implementing this abstract base class your implementations are just like this:

```
public class Example1 : Base<Object1, Service1> 
{
    //Code specific to this implementation
}

public class Example2 : Base<Object2, Service2> 
{
    //Code specific to this implementation
}
```

One thing you never address is how your base will actually get its contents.  You will likely have to pass those in through the constructor.  I have not provided that here since you have not either, but keep in mind you will need to pass *at least* the service down into the base so it can call `Create()` from that passed down service.

Answer (score 0):

If the Model and Object are the same class, your example will work. If Object1 and Object2 are different classes then some tweaking may be needed, or what you're trying to achieve may not be possible.

If they *are* the same class, you could have the Object variable as protected and declare it differently in each derived class's constructor.

If they *are not* the same class but are similar, the Object1, Object2 etc. classes could all inherit from one Object class and the above could be done the same, however this would not be useful if Object1 and Object2 are wildy different.

If I understand what you're trying to do, maybe this will help:

```
public class Base
{
  public Object model;
  protected Service service;

  protected bool Create()
  {
          try
        {
            Model = Service.Create(Model);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
  }
}
public class Example1 : Base
{
  public Example1() //Assign specifics in constructor
  {
    model = model1;
    service = service1;
  }
}
public class Example2 : Base
{
  public Example2() //Assign specifics in constructor
  {
    model = model2;
    service = service2;
  }
}
```

If this doesn't help then maybe what you're looking for is abstract classes/methods but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface IModel { }

interface IService<out TModel>
{
    TModel Create(IModel model);
}

interface IModelService<TModel, TService> where TModel : IModel where TService : IService<TModel>
{
    TModel Model { get; set; }
    TService Service { get; set; }
}

class ExampleModel : IModel { }

class ExampleService : IService<ExampleModel>
{
    public ExampleModel Create(TModel model)
    {
        return new ExampleModel();
    }
}

class Example : ExampleBase<ExampleModel, ExampleService>
{

}

abstract class ExampleBase<TModel, TService> : IModelService<TModel, TService> where TModel : IModel where TService : IService<TModel>
{
    public TModel Model { get; set; }
    public TService Service { get; set; }

    protected bool Create()
    {
        //do what you must
    }
}
```

abstract class with generic type arguments and few interfaces for defining and constraining

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can use [Template_method_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) to solve your problem, because every subclass has its own Sevice object.

Make an `IService` interface be `Service` class contract. 
There is a contract `TModel Create<TModel>(TModel model);` in `IService`.

```
public interface IService {
    TModel Create<TModel>(TModel model);
}
```

then let `Base` class be an abstract class with generics, which can let subclass inheritance, make a hang method `protected abstract IService GetService();` to let subclass provide the `Service` object.

```
public abstract class Base<TModel> 
{
    public TModel Model { get; set; }
    protected abstract IService GetService();

    protected bool Create()
    {
        IService service = GetService();
        try
        {
            Model = service.Create(Model);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Your subclass can inheritance `Base<Object1>` and set its `Model` Type, and provide a service object belonging to this class.

```
public class Example1 : Base<Object1>
{
    protected override IService GetService()
    {
        return new Service1();
    }
}
```